# Как можно убрать этот лимит

Tags: php, laravel

Есть таблица и в нем запись длинной 1886209. Когда достаю эту записть то получаю строку длиной  1048576. как могу получить всю запись ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `PHP` в `PDO` размер буфера по умолчанию `1мб` (соответствует вашему значению в 1048576)

> PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE (integer)
>
> Максимальный размер буфера.
>   По умолчанию равен 1 Мб. Эта константа не поддерживается при
>   компиляции вместе с mysqlnd.

Источник 
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php

---

Для `Laravel` попробуйте в `config/database.php` подправить `options` для `mysql`, увеличив, например, в 2 раза:

```
'options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 2097152 // (1048576 * 2)
)
```